# The existence of an elliptic curve with a specific Galois representation induced by a character

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, elliptic-curves

In Kevin Buzzard's [survey article on potential modularity](http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/papers/survey.pdf) Buzzard writes:

> Let us say that we have an elliptic
>   curve $E$ over a totally real ﬁeld $F$,
>   and we want to prove that $E$ is
>   potentially modular (that is, that $E$
>   becomes modular over a ﬁnite extension
>   ﬁeld $F^{′}$ of $F$, also assumed totally
>   real). Here is  a strategy. Say $p$ is
>   a large prime such that $E[p]$ is
>   irreducible. Let us write down a
>   random odd $2$-dimensional mod $ℓ$
>   Galois representation $\rho_{ℓ} :
> > Gal(\overline{F}/F)  → GL(2,\mathbf{F}_ℓ )$ which is
>   induced from a character; because this
>   representation is induced it is known
>   to be modular. Now let us consider the
>   moduli space parametrising elliptic
>   curves $A$ equipped with
>
> 1. An isomorphism $A[p] \cong E[p] $
> 2. An isomorphism $A[ℓ]\cong ρ_ℓ$
>
> This moduli problem will be
>   represented by some modular curve,
>   whose connected components will be
>   twists of $X(pℓ)$ and hence, if $p$
>   and $ℓ$ are large, will typically have
>   large genus. However, such a curve may
>   well still have lots of rational
>   points, as long as I am allowed to
>   look for such things over an arbitrary
>   ﬁnite extension $F^{′}$ of $F$ !

It's not immediately obvious to me that there's an elliptic curve $A$ over some $F^{′}$ satisfying the second condition alone (never mind satisfying both conditions simultaneously). Is there a simple explanation for why there should be such an $A$? Did Professor Buzzard mean "consider the set of A such that $A[ℓ]\cong ρ_ℓ$ for *some* representation induced by a character" (as opposed to a particular one)?

Answer (score 8):

In this context, if $\rho$ is a mod $\ell$ representation of $Gal(\overline{F} / F)$, and $A$ is an elliptic curve over an extension $F' / F$, then the statement "$A[\ell] \cong \rho$" needs a little bit of interpretation, because the two sides are representations of different things: $A[\ell]$ is a mod $\ell$ representation of the subgroup $Gal(\overline{F} / F') \subset Gal(\overline{F} / F)$. So the statement is to be read as "$A[\ell]$ is isomorphic as a $Gal(\overline{F} / F')$-representation to the *restriction* of $\rho$". Now, the bigger $F'$ is, the weaker this condition becomes: in particular, if we take *any* elliptic curve $A$ over $F$ and define $F'$ to be the extension of $F$ generated by the $\ell$-torsion points of $A$ and the splitting field of $\rho$, then the statement is automatic (both sides are the trivial representation).

(This is kind of a stupid example, but maybe you can believe now that there exist non-stupid examples as well!)

Comment: David, the $A[\rho]$ in the third line should be $A[l]$.

Comment: Good point. This doesn't address my question of whether one can get *any* representation induced by a character can be gotten from an elliptic curve, but it helps highlight how potential modularity theorems can be proved.

Comment: If that doesn't address your question, I'm not entirely sure what your question is. Certainly not every mod $\ell$ representation of $Gal(\overline{F} / F)$ can be realized in the $\ell$-torsion of an elliptic curve over $F$; but the restriction of any such representation to $Gal(\overline{F} / F')$ can be realized by an elliptic curve over some big enough $F'$, simply because that restriction can be made trivial.

Comment: PS: Don't be tempted to read "$A[\ell] \cong \rho$" as "the image of $\Gal(\overline{F} / F)$ acting on $\rho$ and of $\Gal(\overline{F} / F')$ acting on $A[\ell]$ coincide as subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_\ell)$". Although plausible, this reading isn't what's meant here at all.